# How to change the style of tab indicator (default one is an underline ) of tabbed activity in android?

Tags: android, android-tabs

[please click here to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p01v.jpg)

The above picture is a screen shot taken from SYMPTOMATE app. I want to create a tabbed activity same as shown in that picture. As the tabs are swiped each circle is highlighted accordingly. please suggest a way to customize tab indicators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your custom TabLayout you need to write custom resources. In particular you need this drawables.

1. Tab indicator default state (indicator_default.xml)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <shape
          android:innerRadius="0dp"
          android:shape="ring"
          android:thickness="5dp"
          android:useLevel="false">
          <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
      </shape>
   ```
2. Tab indicator selected state (indicator_selected.xml)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <shape
           android:innerRadius="0dp"
           android:shape="ring"
           android:thickness="8dp"
           android:useLevel="false">
           <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   ```
3. Tab indicator selector (indicator_selector.xml)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:drawable="@drawable/indicator_selected"
         android:state_selected="true"/>

      <item android:drawable="@drawable/indicator_default"/>
   </selector>
   ```

Finally you should add your TablLayout in your layout defining the tab background as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabGravity="center"/>
```